# Printing string in heap-allocated memory prints out garbled data

Tags: c, dictionary, malloc

The program must have the following characteristics:
1. Should manage a dictionary of words. 
1.1. Words are stored in a file.
1.2. The user can see the words in the dictionary, correct or 
add new words to the dictionary.
1.3. Each word has a unique ID (numeric) assigned 
automatically by the program.
2. Managed or use dictionary words, the program must load it to a  linked list in memory.

From this I'll make the Hangman game, but for now the code I have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void adiciona(char *ficheiro,char addword){
FILE *f = fopen("dicionario.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
fprintf(f,"%s\n", addword);

fclose(f);
}

int main() {
  int x,j,n,i=0,op;
  int *tab;
  char str[500],addword;
  FILE *f;
  f = fopen("dicionario.txt","r");
if(f==NULL){
   printf("Erro, Dicionário não encontrado!");
   exit(-1);
   }

 //do{
  tab = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if(tab==NULL){
    puts("Nao ha memoria, bye bye!");
    exit(-1);
    }else puts("Memoria alocada");

    while(fgets(str,500,f)!=NULL){
      *(tab+i)=x;
     i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
  printf("\nIntroduza uma das opções:\n1-Ver tabela actual\n2-Adicionar palavra ao Dicionario\n3-Para sair\n\nopcao:");

 scanf("%i",&op);

    switch(op){
   case 1:
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",*(tab+i));
     break;
   case 2:
     printf("\nIntroduza a palavra para adicionar\n:");
     scanf("%s",&addword);
     adiciona("dicionario.txt",addword);
     *tab =addword;
     printf("\n\Palavra Introduzida com sucesso:%c\n",*(tab+i));
     break;}
 //}while(op != 3);
  free(tab);
  return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to check my words on the file, only presents me with @@@@ :\

Can anyone help-me with this?

Comment: You've only `malloc`ed a single `int`.

Comment: `FILE *f = fopen("dicionario.txt", "w");` --> `FILE *f = fopen("dicionario.txt", "a");`

Comment: `*(tab+i)=x;` : set **uninitialize** value of **int**, not CString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems that I see in `main`:

1. You have declared:

   ```
   char str[500],addword;
   ```

   but you are trying to read a string into `addword` in

   ```
   scanf("%s",&addword);
   ```

   If you want read a letter, change the `scanf` line to:

   ```
   scanf("%c",&addword);
   ```

   If you want to read a string, change the definition to:

   ```
   char str[500],addword[500]; // Doesn't have to 500. It needs to be large
                               // enough to read your string.
   ```
2. You have allocated memory for `tab` using:

   ```
   tab = malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```

   That allocated memory to hold only one integer. But you are treating it like it can hold any number of integers in:

   ```
   *(tab+i)=x;
   ```

   when `i > 0` that line will access and write memory that have not allocated.
3. `x` has been defined but not initialized. Yet, you are trying to store its value in `tab` using:

   ```
   *(tab+i)=x;
   ```

   It's not clear what the value of `x` is supposed to be what data `tab` is supposed to hold.

Problems that I see in `adiciona`:

1. I don't know the language you are using. However, I am guessing that you are trying to add something to a file. When you want to add something to a file, you have to open it using "wa".

   ```
   FILE *f = fopen("dicionario.txt", "wa");
   ```
2. You are using the format `%s` in the following line but the argument to print is a `char`.

   ```
   fprintf(f,"%s\n", addword);
   ```

   You can either change the format to `%c` or change the argument, `addword`, to a `char*`.

Comment: Can you exemplify how would that be? Not asking you to do anything for me, just so confused atm :(  and yes its strings because its a start of hangman game !

Answer (score 0):

Your heap-allocated memory area is too small. Use [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc):

```
tab = malloc(sizeof(int));
size_t size = 1;
// ...
while(fgets(str,500,f)!=NULL){
  if (i == size) {
    size *= 2;
    if (!realloc(tab,size)) {
      // error
    }
  }
  tab[i++] = x;
}
// and don't forget to zero-terminate your string ...
```